# two regex tests within regex

Tags: for-loop, preg-replace, preg-match-all

now i have got a problem with preg_match.

This is an example string: "!asksheet!H69=var8949", there can also be more than one var8949 or H69 index in this row. Result shoud be "var33333=var8949"

This is my part:

```
  preg_match_all('#\b\!(.*)\![A-Z]{1,3}\d+\b#', $output, $matches2);
  foreach ($matches2[0] as $match2) {
    $result6 = $db->query("SELECT varid FROM variablen WHERE varimportedindex = '".$match2."' AND projectid = $pid AND varsheetname LIKE '%".$match2."%' ");
    $rowoperation2 = $result6->fetch_assoc();
    if ($rowoperation2['varid'] != "" AND $rowoperation2['varid'] != "0") {
        $output2 = preg_replace("#\b\!(.*)\![A-Z]{1,3}\d+\b#", "var".$rowoperation2['varid']."", $output);
    }
  }
```

Can someone perhaps help?

Thank you,
Regards
Olaf

Comment: there's no such value `var33333` in your example string, why should it be in the result?

Comment: its queried from db and only an example value

Comment: please, i dont know the solution, what does -1 mean?

Comment: how can i get those 2 regex values from preg_match_all('#\b\!(.*)\![A-Z]{1,3}\d+\b#', $output, $matches2);  so first would be "asksheet" and second "H69", but how can i query those?

Comment: @OlafK. It seems that you have upvoted Toto's answer as helpful, but you have not awarded it the green tick which signifies that your issue is completely resolved.  If it is resolved, select Toto's answer as the "accepted answer".  Otherwise the responsibility is on you to explain why your question is not resolved with either a comment on Toto's answer, or an edit to your question.  Please do your part to seek resolution in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a simple `preg_match` instead of preg_match_all, you don't need word boundary and exclamation mark doesn't need to be escaped, the strings you're looking for are in group 1 and 2:

```
$str = '"!asksheet!H69=var8949"';
preg_match('#!(.*?)!([A-Z]{1,3}\d+)#', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => !asksheet!H69
    [1] => asksheet
    [2] => H69
)
```